# How do I make query on MySQL view run faster?

Tags: mysql, performance, view, query-optimization

This query takes 1.2 seconds:

```
select * from alert limit 10000;
```

This query takes 33.99 seconds:

```
select * from alert_version limit 10000;
```

alert_version is a view, which is basically the "alert" table with a subquery:

```
select  `alert`.`Alert_UID` AS `Alert_UID`,`alert`.`Rule_Name` AS `Rule_Name`,
        `alert`.`Headline` AS `Headline`,`alert`.`Severity` AS `Severity`,
        `alert`.`Device_UID` AS `Device_UID`,`alert`.`Configuration_Set_ID` AS `Configuration_Set_ID`,
        `alert`.`Instance_UID` AS `Instance_UID`,`alert`.`Create_DateTime` AS `Create_DateTime`,
        `alert`.`Delete_DateTime` AS `Delete_DateTime`,
        ( SELECT  `version_build`.`Version`
            from  `version_build`
            where  ((`version_build`.`Instance_UID` = `alert`.`Instance_UID`)
                      and  (`version_build`.`Create_DateTime` >= `alert`.`Create_DateTime`)
                   )
            order by  `version_build`.`Create_DateTime`
            limit  1
        ) AS `version`
    from  `alert`
```

When I run EXPLAIN on this query, I get:

```
+----+--------------------+---------------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+---------+----------------------------+--------+------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table         | type | possible_keys                                                                     | key                      | key_len | ref                        | rows   | Extra                                    |
+----+--------------------+---------------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+---------+----------------------------+--------+------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | alert         | ALL  | NULL                                                                              | NULL                     | NULL    | NULL                       | 301274 | NULL                                     |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | version_build | ref  | uid_version_build_create,version_build_Instance_UID,version_build_Create_DateTime | uid_version_build_create | 110     | insight.alert.Instance_UID |      6 | Using where; Using index; Using filesort |
+----+--------------------+---------------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+---------+----------------------------+--------+------------------------------------------+
```

So, what do you think I should do to get acceptable performance?

**UPDATE:**

Per request, adding table information:

```
CREATE TABLE `alert` (
`Alert_UID` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
`Rule_Name` varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL,
`Headline` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`Severity` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
`Device_UID` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
`Configuration_Set_ID` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
`Instance_UID` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
`Create_DateTime` timestamp NOT NULL,
`Delete_DateTime` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`Alert_UID`),
KEY `alert_Create_DateTime` (`Alert_UID`,`Create_DateTime`),
KEY `alert_Headline` (`Headline`),
KEY `alert_Rule_Headline` (`Rule_Name`,`Headline`),
KEY `alert_Instance_UID` (`Instance_UID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |


CREATE TABLE `version_build` (
`Instance_UID` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
`Version` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
`Build` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
`Create_DateTime` timestamp NOT NULL,
UNIQUE KEY `uid_version_build_create` 
(`Instance_UID`,`Version`,`Build`,`Create_DateTime`),
KEY `version_build_Instance_UID` (`Instance_UID`),
KEY `version_build_Create_DateTime` (`Create_DateTime`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

Comment: in my opinion? Stop using subquery. I don't known if it is possible in your case, you need to share also your db schema at least of the tables involved

Comment: What is the ideal format for sharing the schema here?

Comment: Why was my question downvoted?

Comment: Sometimes StackOverflow is not the most welcoming place. For the schema usually the "CREATE TABLE" command is enough to share tables' information.

Comment: @m47730 added the table info now. Sorry for the delay, was on leave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please test carefully! I only made some quick test**

From my point of view the subquery is just an overkill in this query (so the performances are horrible):

```
SELECT
`alert`.`Alert_UID` AS `Alert_UID`,
`alert`.`Rule_Name` AS `Rule_Name`,
`alert`.`Headline` AS `Headline`,
`alert`.`Severity` AS `Severity`,
`alert`.`Device_UID` AS `Device_UID`,
`alert`.`Configuration_Set_ID` AS `Configuration_Set_ID`,
`alert`.`Instance_UID` AS `Instance_UID`,
`alert`.`Create_DateTime` AS `Create_DateTime`,
`alert`.`Delete_DateTime` AS `Delete_DateTime`, 
`version_build`.`Version` AS `version`,
MIN(version_build.Create_DateTime)
FROM alert
LEFT JOIN version_build ON (alert.Instance_UID = version_build.Instance_UID
AND version_build.Create_DateTime >= alert.Create_DateTime)
GROUP BY alert.Alert_UID
```

**Group-By** is not order-wise so is necessary the trick of **MIN** in the select field otherwise the order is unpredictable.
I didn't test the performance, but i guess they are a fraction of subquery.

Now with null values in case the join condition is not satisfied.

Comment: The output from your query isn't the output I need

Comment: @yi1 the order was wrong (DESC instead of ASC), and now output all the fields of your original query plus MIN (you can't rid of these field, just ignore it on app). Could you try now?

Comment: I like your approach. One thing it's missing right now (it seems) is having null when you can't find the version data.

Comment: @yi1 i changed the query as you point out null values were excluded. If you have any other concern, please share some data, it's quite difficult to insert random data and be sure the query is right.

Comment: Very cool @m47730. The data output from your query matches my original one exactly, execution time across the entire database (326,080 resulting rows) was the same for both your query and my original one (both 39-40 seconds). I think this may be thanks to the index rick-james suggested, but am not sure.

Comment: @Yi1, glad to be helpful. The fields involved in the query are: Instance_UID and Create_DateTime (for both table) and Alert_UID (so Rick James suggestion only partially improved). The trick is the rid off the subquery: remember a subquery is a query that wait for result of another query so if the table has a lot of rows like in your case the wait time is a lot. I don't get it, but you say that your query with subquery performs as the same of mine with join?

Answer (score 2):

What will you do with 10K rows?  That is usually too much for an app to handle.

Without an `ORDER BY`, which 10K rows are you hoping to get?  It is unpredictable.  With an `ORDER BY`, the query may be even slower.

The subquery is the performance killer.  Live with the speed.  However, you seem to be doing a "groupwise max" in an inefficient way.  This index may help:

```
INDEX(Instance_UID, Create_DateTime, Version)   -- in this order!
```

More on groupwise-max:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max

Comment: The 10K rows was just a sample. Actually what I'm doing is pulling the entire query output into an app. With the simple query, it's bearable. With the subquery information, it's 33x longer, which isn't bearable. I looked at your solutions but didn't gain much of a performance boost. Do you think this is a typical case where simply creating an alert_version table and filling it up with a scheduled event would be the best solution? That way time is spent by a cron and the query is very fast.

Comment: And my answer is "don't do groupwise-max _that way_".